# How to create a table with multiple classification in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having problems in create a report table with a data frame like this:

```
   id sex    age    location
   1   m   0-17       Miami
   2   f  18-64 Los Angeles
   3   f over64     Ontario
   4   m  18-64       Paris
   5   m  18-64     Ontario
   6   m over64       Miami
   7   f over64       Miami
   8   f  18-64 Los Angeles
   9   m  18-64       Other
  10   m over64       Other
```

my desired table should look like this:
[Deired Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx0lt.jpg)

Any idea how to do it.

Comment: check out the `gt` package https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/creating-summary-lines.html

Comment: i tried to use the gt package but i can't figure it out how to get that 3 different groupby and how to put the summarise as columns and not as rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you look through the packages `gt` and `gtsummary`, you'll find what you're looking for. For example, this is close to the example you provided as your desired output.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)

df1 <- read.table(header = T, 
                  text = "Id Sex Age Location # notice I capitalized names
1 m 0-17 Miami
2 f 18-64 Los.Angeles
3 f over64 Ontario
4 m 18-64 Paris
5 m 18-64 Ontario
6 m over64 Miami
7 f over64 Miami
8 f 18-64 Los.Angeles
9 m 18-64 Other
10 m over64 Other", sep = " ")

tbl_summary(df1[,2:4]) %>% add_n() %>% bold_labels
```

This is the output table.

[image]

If you want to customize it, pipe in `as_gt()` and then use any of the functions in the `gt` package to customize it further.